# how to change the sound tone in C#

Tags: c#, api, frequency, audio

i'm developing an application that aims to record the voice of the user and play it in different tones ( female tone , robot tone )

i wanted to know what changes do i need to do in the sound that needed to achieve those voices (the pitch of the female and the robot)

Comment: You would have to record the audio in memory, then adjust the tone of the audio in memory, and then play it back.  You could do this with a file also of course.  You have to first determine what audio format you are going to use.

Comment: i wanted to know what changes do i need to do in the sound  that needed to achieve those voices  (the pitch of the female and the robot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SoundTouch](http://code.google.com/p/soundtouchnet/) is an open-source audio processing library for changing the Tempo, Pitch and Playback Rates of audio streams or audio files.

changing the Pitch is what you're looking for...